# Obfuscating using ConfuserEX

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate one of my DLLs using [confuserEX](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx), the rest is standard code. But one has a proprietary algorithm in it that I'd like to obfuscate.

The project in question obfuscates ok and is signed, all that works fine.
However, having asked the reference not to copy local or build I copy the obfuscated DLL into the `/bin/release` directory and I get a verification exception. I would be grateful if someone could advise me step by step how to go from a compiled DLL to running it obfuscated.

Many Thanks

Dom (Obfuscation Newbie)

Comment: Open an issue at their GitHub page and discuss with the developers.

Comment: I think it's a usage rather than a development issue, I think I'm  missing a step...build..obfuscate...overwrite with obfuscated dll...try and run.  Is what I'm doing but it seems that it is hanging on to a reference to the original dll or something.